# oauth2-server and silex with user authentification

Tags: oauth-2.0, silex, authentication

I am new in Silex PHP framework and OAuth2, I could implement oauth2 server but there is no user authentication, I mean when user press authorize button it redirects directly authorization page where system will ask user allows this app or not, but without any user authentication I couldn't implement there sign in function. Is there anybody implement oauth2 and silex php framework together. Please someone can it would be very good thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I have never used OAuth at all, but have seen some ready components like this one - [Silex OAuthServiceProvider](https://github.com/gigablah/silex-oauth). Maybe you can use the code and adjust it to your needs. Good luck!